# Javascript, copy text field to new li class

Tags: javascript, copy, field, zendesk

**UPDATED, TO BE MORE CLEAR:**

**My current field that contains the value ‘1201026404’ (which will change every time) :**

```
<input id="ticket_fields_20323656" name="ticket[fields][20323656]" size="30" style="width:125px;" type="text" value="1201026404" tabindex="11">
```

**The LI where I want the copied value ‘1201026404’ (which will change every time) to go when the page loads:**

```
<ul class="multi_value_field" style="width: 99.5%;">
<li class="choice" choice_id="1201026404">1201026404<a class="close">×</a><input type="hidden" name="ticket[set_tags][]" value="1201026404" style="display: none;"></li>
</ul>
```

**The Javascript that I have already made but need help with:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656");
    var n2 = ‘what goes here??’
    n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is `ticket_fields_20323656` the only input that matches the pattern `ticket_fields_` or are there others? And which of the inputs in `<ul>` are you copying the value to?

Comment: Hey Michael, that is the unique id of the field that contains the value (which could be any number) which I want copied into an li.

Comment: is it possible that it could just add another like this:

<li class="choice" choice_id="2_live_tomorrow">2_live_tomorrow<a class="close">×</a><input type="hidden" name="ticket[set_tags][]" value="2_live_tomorrow" style="display: none;"></li>

but with my value from the 'ticket_fields_20323656'?

Comment: Yes, but what I am asking is - are there _other_ inputs like `ticket_fields_20323656` having different numbers `ticket_fields_xxxxxxxxx` or is this the only such input on the page?

Comment: Hey sorry yes there are other ticket_fields with different id's

Comment: So do you want to capture all of them, or only this one specific one 20323656?

Comment: Just the one, this is what I have so far:

<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("???");
    n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>

It does get the the value of the first field I just don't know how to specify 'n2' if you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work in firefox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656");
    var n2 = document.querySelectorAll("ul.multi_value_field li:first");
    n2.innerHTML = n1.value;
}
</script>
```

this uses querySelectorAll which doesnt exist in IE6,7,8 - otherwise you need to use the id of the element which im not sure you have

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use an ID on the li element.

```
 <li id="choice_20323656">
```

then you can copy it like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("choice_20323656");
    n2.innerHTML = n1.value;
}
</script>
```

### EDIT:

If you can use jQuery 1.6 or up, this will work:

```
$("#ticket_fields_20323656").keyup(function(e) {
    $(".choice")
        .attr("choice_id",e.currentTarget.value)
        .html(e.currentTarget.value
              + "<a class=\"close\">×</a><input" 
              + " type=\"hidden\" name=\"ticket" 
              + "[set_tags][]\" value=\"" 
              + e.currentTarget.value 
              + "\" style=\"display: none;\">");
});​
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/V2L25/, However you should know, if you have multiple things with the class `choice` their value's going to change in the same way like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/V2L25/4/

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately the html is not editable so I wouldn't be able to modify the id of 'choice'

Is there no way to just add this exactly using javascript:

<li class="choice" choice_id="1201026404">1201026404<a class="close">×</a><input type="hidden" name="ticket[set_tags][]" value="1201026404" style="display: none;"></li>

Comment: @Charlie, can you use a library like jQuery? Vanilla javascript isn't very good at getting class names cross-browser, and I'm not sure if `getAttribute` works with non-standard attributes, I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Hey JKirchartz, yes I think I can use jQuery. If it helps this will be a custom widget in Zendesk

Comment: @Charlie I'm not sure of zendesk's system, but I've updated my post with some jQuery.

Comment: @Charlie I recently became familiar with the Zendesk system. I feel your pain. It seems they use jquery in [noConflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)